# Yii2 Client установка тела POST запроса

Tags: php, yii2, curl

В официальной документации `Yii2 Http Client` указан такой способ передачи `POST` параметров:

```
use yii\httpclient\Client;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->createRequest()
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->setUrl('http://example.com/api/1.0/users')
    ->setData(['name' => 'John Doe', 'email' => 'johndoe@example.com'])
    ->send();
if ($response->isOk) {
    $newUserId = $response->data['id'];
}
```

[ЛИНК](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/basic-usage.md)

т.е. передаю параметры в виде `'name' => 'value'`.

Но как передать параметры сразу строкой? Например, у меня есть переменная, в которой  `POST` параметры указаны в виде строки:

```
$postData = 'param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3';
```

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
$response = $client->createRequest()
->setMethod('POST')
->setUrl('http://example.com/api/1.0/users')
->setData($postData)
->send();
```

И... ничего не выходит. Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать **[parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)**, чтобы преобразовать такую строку в ассоциативный массив

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня может возникнуть такая ситуация, что нужно будет передать строку, в которой название параметра повторяется. Например: `param=value&param=value2&param=value3`. В приведенном примере название параметра одно и то же, а вот значения разные. Если прогонять это все через parse_url, получится массив вида ключ => значение. Ключ, насколько мне известно, должен быть уникальным. А в моем случае это не так....

Comment: @UnnamedStar283 один и тот же параметр не может иметь много значений, это нонсенс. Если планируется передать массив значений - то он передаётся по-другому, но никак не `param=value&param=value2&param=value3`, т.к. это неправильно в принципе.

Comment: Я кстати перепутал, не parse_url, а parse_str .... поправил........ в общем, если передавать массивы - то тогда будет работать как надо

Comment: Я согласен с вами - ситуация, когда один и тот же параметр принимает много значений, однозначно, неправильная. Однако я хотел бы именно такую логику реализовать. Поэтому вопрос остается открытым - возможно ли как нибудь это сделать?

Comment: Либо передавать массив, как я уже отметил, т.е. всего-то банально вместо `param=value&param=value2&param=value3`  писать `param[]=value&param[]=value2&param[]=value3`  либо писать свой метод преобразования